# JPA find from composite Key

Tags: jpa

I have a class like this...

```
@Entity
public class User{
  private String userId;
  @Id
  public String getUserId(){
    return userId;
  }
  public void setUserId(String userId){
    this.userId = userId;
  }
}

@Embeddible
public class RegPk{
  private String serial;
  private String userId;
  ....
}

@Entity
@IdClass(RegPk.class)
public class Registration {
  private String userId, serial;

  private User user

  @Id
  @Column(name="SRL_C")
  public String getSerial() {return serial;}
  public void setSerial(String serial) {this.serial = serial;}
  @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @JoinColumn(name="USERID", referencedColumnName="USERID", nullable = false)
  public User getUser() {return user;}
  public void setUser(User user) {this.user = user;}
  @Id
  @Column(name="USERID", nullable = false)
  public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }
  public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }

}

RegPk pk = new RegPk();
pk.setSerial(dr.getSerial());
pk.setUserId(dr.getUserId());
Registration userOld =  em.find(Registration.class, pk);
```

But when I try to run it I get null back. I swear I thought I had it working so...

1.) is this kind of thing even possible?
2.) what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, provided you use the [MapsId annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html). Otherwise, you have two different fields mapped to the same column, which is invalid.

The javadoc provides an example which almost matches exactly with your situation.

Comment: So in this case would my column annotation be in the pk class?

Comment: Still getting back null, I will work on creating a second example as you have described. Maybe I did something easy wrong